# Netty bind ChannelFuture never completes

Tags: tcp, netty

Say I have a process already using port N to talk to another server.
If I try to bind to port N as server what will happen?

Should this fail with address already in use?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the protocol and socket options it will either succeed or fail. For DatagramChannel it will just succeed, for TCP with "NO" SO_REUSEPORT" it should fail. If this is not the case please open an issue in the netty issue tracker with a reproducer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It works as expected but Exception is thrown instead of ChannelFuture is notified. May be will create an issue to understand better.